# Deploying a React app statically for development purposes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, wildfly, babeljs

I have a React project that I generated using create-react-app. It uses yarn, webpack, babel (JSX) etc., but the circumstances I found myself in require me to deploy it on a Wildfly server, which can only serve static files (besides java EE apps ofc).

I can compile the code using `yarn build` and deploy it on the server, but what I really want to achieve, is to have a non-uglified/minified static form of my app available for runtime editing during development, the way I can do it on node.

I think its possible to have babel compile JSX/ES6 on the client side, which seems perfect for my purposes, but I need to also somehow include the modules which webpack usually takes care of. How should I approach this?

I'm new to this domain of SWE, thanks.

Comment: Isn't `webpack-dev-server` enought ? (using `yarn start`)

Comment: As @Okazari mentioned, with CRA using "yarn start" should fire up a browser instance and CRA will include the source maps to show your unaltered code in the devtools window for debugging. Is this not working for you?

Comment: That's not sufficient because I have a backend running on wildfly which uses its integrated security module for logins. Before adding this security feature, the proxy directive in package.json served me fine for backend API calls. But now, I can no longer make these requests.